# Tabulator 4.1- Data is not populating in Table on IE 11

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, tabulator

Data is not populating inside the table. But when I am opening console or performing `addRow` operation, data gets updated.
Below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get("./resources/json/result.json", function(data, status) {
    createEmpDetailTbl(JSON.parse(data));
});

function createEmpDetailTbl(jsonData) {
table = new Tabulator("#emp-detail-table", {
    data : jsonData,
    height : "100%",
    layout : "fitColumns",
    tooltips:true,
    tooltipsHeader: true,
    addRowPos:"top",
    pagination : "local",
    paginationSize : 10,
    columns : [ {
        title : "Actions",
        field : "username",
        //sorter : "string",
        width : 100,
        frozen : true,
        headerSort : false,
        formatter : actionRowIcon,
        cellClick : function(e, cell) {
            //console.log("Event Source: "+e.srcElement.id);
            //console.log("Cell Value: "+cell.getValue());
            if('del' == e.srcElement.id){
                var row = cell.getRow();
                row.delete().then(function(){
                    //run code after row has been deleted
                    alert('Row Deleted Successfully');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/YourController",
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            //$("#content").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(function(error){
                    //handle error deleting row
                });
                var rowIndex = row.getIndex();
                //console.log('Row Data: '+row);
                //console.log('Row Position: '+row.getPosition(true));
            }
        }
    }, {
        title : "Employee ID",
        field : "username",
        //sorter : "string",
        width : 120,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false,
        editor:"input",
        frozen : true
    }, {
        title : "Full Name",
        field : "fname",
        //sorter : "string",
        width : 120,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false,
        frozen : true
    }, {
        title : "Email Address",
        field : "email",
        //sorter : "string",
        width : 170,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false,
        cellClick : function(e, cell) {
            //console.log("cell click")
        },
    }, {
        title : "OUC",
        field : "ouc",
        //sorter : "string",
        width : 70,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false
    }, {
        title : "LOB",
        field : "lob",
        width : 70,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false,
        //sorter : "string"
    }, {
        title : "Type of Redundancy",
        field : "tyRedun",
        //sorter : "string",
        width : 120,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false,
    }, {
        title : "Type of Notice Period",
        field : "tyNoticePeriod",
        //sorter : "string",
        width : 80,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false
    }, {
        title : "Notice Period",
        field : "noticePeriod",
        //sorter : "string",
        width : 70,
        align : "left",
        editor:"select", 
        editorParams:{values:["1 Month", "2 Month", "3 Month", "4 Month"]},
        headerSort : false
    }, {
        title : "Proposed Exit Date",
        field : "proExitDate",
        //sorter : "date",
        width : 80,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false
    }, {
        title : "Consultation Manager UIN",
        field : "conManagerUin",
        width : 80,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false
        //sorter : "number",
    }, {
        title : "Consultation Date",
        field : "conDate",
        //sorter : "date",
        width : 80,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false
    }, {
        title : "Pension Contribution",
        field : "pensionContri",
        //sorter : "number",
        width : 100,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false
    }, {
        title : "Car Cash Allowance",
        field : "carCashAllowance",
        //sorter : "number",
        width : 100,
        align : "left",
        headerSort : false
    } ],
    renderStarted:function(){
        $('#loading').show();
    },renderComplete:function(){
        $('#loading').hide();
    },
    cellEdited:function(row){

        //row - row component
        //console.log('Changed......'+row.getData().username);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            //url: './resources/json/employee.json',
            url: projectOptions.restUrl+'employee/'+row.getData().username,
            dataType:'text',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            success:function(response) {
                if(response != ""){
                    var data=[];
                    data.push(response);
                    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
                    //table.updateData(JSON.parse(data));
                    table.addData(JSON.parse(data));
                    $('.alert').hide();
                } else{
                    $('#error-txt').text('').text('Employee data not found.');
                    $('.alert').show();
                }

            },
            complete:function(){
                $('#loading').hide();
            },
            error:function(err, xhr, msg){
                alert(err+"-------------------"+xhr);
            }
        });

    }
});
}
```

**JSON:**

```
[{
"dn": null,
"username": "23456789",
"password": null,
"displayName": null,
"fname": "John",
"lname": "Smith209884",
"email": "x.x@wer.com",
"ouc": "TBS23B",
"lob": "wer",
"jobcode": "STST05",
"employer": "NO Plc",
"ldg": "GB LDG",
"origHireDate": "1980-09-01",
"serviceDate": "1980-09-01",
"terminationDate": null,
"authorities": [],
"accountNonExpired": true,
"accountNonLocked": true,
"credentialsNonExpired": true,
"enabled": true,
"timeBeforeExpiration": 2147483647,
"graceLoginsRemaining": 2147483647,
"name": "John Smith209884"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make the GET request yourself, Tabulator can do that for you.

Instead of using the ***data*** property, use the ***ajaxURL*** and pass it the url:

```
table = new Tabulator("#emp-detail-table", {
    ajaxURL: "./resources/json/result.json",
    height : "100%",
    layout : "fitColumns",
...
});
```

If the table isnt loading the data it suggests it is in the wrong format, have you checked your console logs? Tabulator will leave a message in the logs explaining why it cant  load the data. it will be expecting an array of objects:

```
[
    {...},
    {...},
]
```

Comment: getting Ajax Load Error:  ReferenceError: 'fetch' is undefined error on IE, I have also included polyfill.js but error on IE is still there. Code is working fine of chrome.

Comment: Have a look at the [IE Compatability](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/browsers#ie) section in the docs, there are a couple of polyfills you need to load if you want it to work on IE

Comment: I have included below js but still not working.
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.4/fetch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>

Comment: you need to include them before the Tabulator library, if you have then you wont get that error

Comment: Error is gone but issue is still there. On IE Edge data is not rendering. :(

Comment: That suggests you are creating the table before the element is visible in the DOM. the table needs to be visible for the virtual DOM to draw the data correctly as invisible elements have no dimensions. either make the element visible before calling the constructor or call the redraw function on the table after u make it visible

Comment: Tried to use $("#emp-detail-table").tabulator("redraw", true); but getting error on IE. Object doesn't support property or method 'tabulator'